# Pass multiple parameters to the controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes

To access resource I have to pass two ids, because two ids build the key.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.CallerId, customerId = item.CustomerId })
```

I get `null`s in controller action with following signature:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id, int? customerId)
```

I use default routing. What should I do to pass both ids?

Comment: I'm not sure of the details of `.asp` but it sounds like you need a `struct`

Comment: Can you check what link actually is created as result? `customerId` should become query parameter and it should simply work... [edit] post with resulting url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to get this done. One of the ways is to build a ViewModel to contain both Ids. Another way is to use the `HttpGetAttribute` to specify the route:

```
[HttpGet("Details/{id}/{customerId}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id, int? customerId)
```

Here, `{id}` will map to `id` and `{customerId}` to `customerId`, provided that the received values are `int`

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to define the source for second ID, can be from header, query param, or route param.
Default routing defines the route as `/{controller}/{action}/{?id}` as you can see, it tells MVC where to get the id from the route.

In your case, I suggest sending both IDs as query params.

This link could be helpful for you on how to pass argument as query params.